# Appengine login and logout behavior

Tags: google-app-engine

I deployed a web application using Google accounts Authentication on the appengine server. If I log out the app with the link from create_logout_url(), my Gmail in the same browser is also  logged out. Is that normal behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is absolutely normal. My experience is the same as yours.

Many Google services use the same cookies I think, If you log into your Gmail, you can access Google Reader without logging in again.

It is for security purpose I think.